# How can I use two NotifyIcons in C# without the second one disappearing when i hover the mouse over?

Tags: c#, system, notify, trayicon, tray

I Have a VS2008 app that needs to display two notifyIcons in the System tray. One is the main application icon, which allows quick access to the GUI. The second is a "new message" icon, which is displayed when a new message arrives, and hidden when the user double-clicks on it, much like the new Outlook mail message icon.

The problem i am having is the second message icon is hidden whenever the mouse is moved over the system tray. The first icon behaves as expected, and remains in the system tray while the application is running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this be related with a Windows glitch, which doesn't refresh the system tray? I mean, if you have an application with a systray icon, and the application dies hard the icon will stay until you hover your mouse over it (there for the systray isn't refreshed until that moment).

Comment: Post code, show how you display the message icon.  And document whether the icon can be brought back when you click "Show hidden icons".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - this was partly due to windows glitch and a bug in my code. 
Seems the icon will not stay visible when showing a baloon tip - it must be forced visible before showing the baloon tip. The icon did not refresh until i moved my mouse over the tray.